# ffmpeg: Audio/Video Fade in/out

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, fading

I have this working Script with Audio fading.  How can i input also a Fading for the video in and out. It always gives me an error :

***"Option filter:v (set stream filtergraph) cannot be applied to input url ./mp3/conv/1.m4a -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to."***

**This Works with audio-fading:**

```
 ffmpeg  -ss 00:00:00 -t 90 -i "concat:intermediate0.ts|concat:intermediate1.ts"  
-i "./mp3/conv/1.m4a" -af "afade=t=out:st=84:d=6"  -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 
video/out515.mp4 -y
```

**This doesn't Work with Audio+Video-Fading:**

```
ffmpeg  -ss 00:00:00 -t 90-i  "concat:intermediate0.ts|intermediate1.ts" 
-filter:v 'fade=in:0:30,fade=out:250:30' -i "./mp3/conv/1.m4a" 
-af "afade=t=out:st=84:d=6" -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0  video/out515.mp4 -y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Video filters are output options, and so, go after all inputs:

```
ffmpeg  -ss 00:00:00 -t 90-i  "concat:intermediate0.ts|intermediate1.ts" -i "./mp3/conv/1.m4a" 
        -af "afade=t=out:st=84:d=6" -vf 'fade=in:0:30,fade=out:250:30'
        -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0  video/out515.mp4 -y
```

Comment: THanks! 
here is a Video/Audio Fadein out script:

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Final Result that Works

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 90 -i "concat:intermediate0.ts" 
-ss 00:00:00 -t 90 -i ".\mp3\conv\1.m4a" -af "afade=t=out:st=84:d=6" 
-vf "fade=in:0:25,fade=out:2225:25" -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 video/out515.mp4 -y
```